# Как умножить каждое n-ое число в массиве?

Tags: javascript, массивы, перебор, умножение

подскажите пожалуйста, как умножить и изменить каждое n-е число в массиве?
Для примера, мне нужно умножить каждое второе число в массиве на 2, написал код, но изменений в массиве не происходит.

```js
function doubleEveryOther(a) {
  for (let i = 1; i < a.length; i = i + 2) {
    const elem = a[i];
    elem * 2;
  };
  return a;
};

console.log(doubleEveryOther([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  for (let i = 1; i < a.length; i=i+2) {
        const elem = a[i];
        elem * 2;//<--- это куда-то в воздух 
        a[i] = elem * 2; // перезаписано! 
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так (если не отходить от вашего стиля)

```js
function doubleEveryOther(a) {

  let arr = a;

  for (let i = 1; i < a.length; i = i + 2) {
    arr[i] = arr[i] * 2;
  };

  return arr;
};

console.log(doubleEveryOther([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Comment: Можно и так, но мне нужно было не создавать новый массив, а изменить уже имеющийся. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Vlodek, он не новый, это тот же  массив, а "arr " ссылка на него. Есть такой принцип не изменяемости входных параметров. Но тогда нужно было сделать так:  let arr = [...a] и это уже новый массив;

Comment: Дейстивтельно, мне показалось что там не arr = a, a arr = [] :)) Невнимательный я